# ANTLR4 parsing error: no viable alternative at input

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4, parse-error, parsing-error

I have a grammar which is obviously erroneous as parsing a simple file generates strange error messages.

I simplified the following grammar as much as I could without altering the error (if you remove `'this'` the tree gui output of ANTLRWorks colors the token `int` of the sample file differently although the structure seems to be equal).

```
grammar DepClsJ_no_java_debug;

module   : ( methodDecl )* ;

methodDecl   : pathType Identifier '()' block ;

pathType   : Identifier | 'this' ;

block   : '{'
    ( localDecl ';'  )*
    ( statement  )*
    ( expr  )?
    '}'   ;

localDecl   : pathType Identifier ( '=' expr )?;

statement   : block | expr ';' ;

expr   : dotExpr ( '=' dotExpr  )* ;    dotExpr   : Identifier ( '.' Identifier )* ;

Identifier   : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
```

Demo code:

```
void main() {
    a = c;
    int b;
}
```

ANTLRWorks 2 gives me the following error messages:

```
line 3:8 no viable alternative at input 'intb'
line 3:9 mismatched input ';' expecting '()'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int b;` is a `localDecl`, which according to the `block` rule in your grammar cannot appear after the first `statement`. If you had instead relaxed your grammar by using the following, then you could have used a parse tree listener to produce a meaningful error message after the parse completed successfully.

```
block
  : '{'
    (localDecl ';' | statement)*
    expr?
    '}'
  ;
```

Comment: OMG how could I not see that?